# Get positions of all non zero matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to find all non zero elements of a table and I want to create a list that contains the name of the table the element was removed from, the position of the element, and the value of the element.

Then to the generated list I would like to apply a replacment rule to the row and the column.

```
rule = {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}

{ {tablename, row, col, value} }
```

For example I have tried

```
dataTable1 = {{1,0,0}, {0,1,0}, {0,0,-1}} 

Position[Abs[dataTable1], # > 0 &]
```

but I am unable to get get the position.  I would like the final out put to be

```
 { {"dataTable1", 1,1,1}, {"dataTable1", 2,2,1}, {"dataTable1", 3,3,-1} }
```

If we apply the replacment.

```
  { {"dataTable1", 1,1,1}, {"dataTable1", 2,2,1}, {"dataTable1", 3,3,-1} } /. rule
```

Then the output should be

```
 { {"dataTable1", "a","a",1}, {"dataTable1", "b","b",1}, {"dataTable1", "c","c",-1} }
```

Comment: `SparseArray[dataTable1]["NonzeroPositions"]` gives you your `{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}` and `"NonzeroValues"` gives `{1, 1, -1}`. It is not quite clear from your question how the tables are organized to be able to extract their names, but I suppose you can figure the rest of it out by yourself.

Comment: In this case their names are just the name of variable. IE: `datatable1` is named `"datatable1"`

Comment: @olliepower: lol, typing as you commented... same idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
info[tbl_] := With[{s = SparseArray[tbl]},
  ArrayPad[Append @@@ Transpose[{s["NonzeroPositions"], s["NonzeroValues"]}], 
          {0, {1, 0}}, ToString@Unevaluated@tbl]]

SetAttributes[info, HoldFirst]

result=info[dataTable1]

(* {{"dataTable1", 1, 1, 1}, {"dataTable1", 2, 2, 1}, {"dataTable1", 3, 3, -1}} *)
```

As to the second part of your query, assume the result from the `info` function is in a symbol named `result`, then using your example rule list,

```
MapAt[(# /. rule) &, result, {All, 2 ;; 3}]

(* 
 {{"dataTable1", "a", "a", 1}, {"dataTable1", "b", "b", 1},{"dataTable1", "c", "c", -1}} 
*)
```

Comment: this worked.  I have one other question.  What if I want to apply a replacemnt rule to only the positions after the list has been constructed.  For example `info[dataTables1] /. rules` Where rules should only apply to the second and third elements of each sublist.

Comment: @olliepower: Need to clarify what you mean, and to where (replace things in the generated list, the original array?). Perhaps append to your OP.

Comment: I have appended to my OP.  Thank you once again.

Comment: @olliepower: appended answer

Comment: Where is `"NonzeroPositions"` and `"NonzeroValues"` documented?

Comment: I just found it ... [SparseArray properties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/what-are-sparsearray-properties-how-and-when-should-they-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
SetAttributes[getPos, HoldFirst];
getPos[t_Symbol] := 
 Module[{pos = Position[Abs[t], _?Positive]}, 
  Join[ConstantArray[{ToString[Unevaluated@t]}, Length[pos]], pos, 
   List /@ Extract[t, pos], 2]]

getPos[dataTable1]
```

> ```
> {{"dataTable1", 1, 1, 1}, {"dataTable1", 2, 2, 1}, {"dataTable1", 3, 3, -1}}
> ```

Comment: The only problem with this code is if a row of the table contains all zeros.  then I get `{{"dataTable1"}}`.  I would not like to have those in the output.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check new version.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov please take a look at [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)