# How to find non zero elements of a list containing zeros and symbols

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list, obtained after differentiating a list of expressions, which contains zeros and symbols, say:

```
A = {x1^2, x2^2, x3^2, x4^2}
D[A,x3]
```

results in the list:

```
{0, 0, 2 x3, 0}
```

How do I get the position of the non-zero entry, mathematica cannot compare symbols to zero directly. I could convert the elements of the list to strings but is there a faster way?

Comment: Have a look at  `===` vs `==`. Posting your code is also a good idea.

Comment: `Position[D[A, x3], x_ /; ! TrueQ[x == 0], {1}, Heads -> False]`

Comment: Also `Position[D[A, x3], Except[0], 1, Heads -> False]`

Comment: Also `ArrayRules[D[A, x3]][[;; -2, 1, 1]]`

Comment: @YvesKlett, my code involves symbolic calculation with many subscripts, which does not look good when posted.

Comment: I see many helpful suggestions. How can I vote up answers? Also @Kuba, where can I read more about the use of x_ /;, I understand that it is supposed to specify a pattern, but I would like to understand the syntax better, Thanks

Comment: @user44406 Take a look at [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html). Also closely related: [46852](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46852/5478) => `SparseArray[list]["NonzeroPositions"]`

Answer (score 6):

I've failed to find good topic to mark it a duplicate so this is the answer.

Let's assume your list is:

```
list = {0, 2 x3, 0.}
```

so we `0` is not `0.` and missing this may cause troubles while pattern matching. Take a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15909/5478) and [there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5154/5478).

```
SparseArray[list]["NonzeroPositions"]
```

> ```
> {{2}}
> ```

or alternatively:

```
Position[list, x_ /; ! TrueQ[x == 0], {1}, Heads -> False]
```

Comment: The `"NonzeroPositions"` method should be the fastest available.  It however does not work on a list that contains other lists, i.e. fails `VectorQ` but does not pass `ArrayQ`.  One could replace `List` expressions first, e.g.: `Replace[list, _List -> 1, {1}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the notes. General answer may be long, I'm no really interested in elaborating this subject, mainly because of lack of knowldge. But if you want to do this I will gladly upvote it and delete mine.

Comment: No need for that. :-)  I think this has it covered now.

Comment: In some use-cases, one might want `Position[list, x_ /; ! PossibleZeroQ[x], {1}, Heads -> False]` or other methods of checking sameness/zero/etc.