# Showing the numbers greater than 0 in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an operation that outputs the list

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
 22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 0}
```

I want it only to output the numbers greater than 0, is there a command or a short code to do this? I haven't been able to do it. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html - `Select[Positive] @ list`.

Comment: may be `Cases[lst, x_ /; x > 0]`

Comment: `SparseArray[list]["NonzeroValues"]`

Comment: Also: [(47214)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47214/121)

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, \
22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 0}

Select[data, # > 0 &]
```

**Reference:**

[Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

**Guide:**

[Elements of Lists](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ElementsOfLists.html)